# Multiple redirects to one site with different parameters in http request in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

How do I handle multiple redirects to one site with different parameters in the HTTP body? In my code, I have a loop with HTTP redirect... It supposes to loop and do redirects with different parameters so many times as I have different parameters. But it just does one-time redirect and goes to this web site, so I end up with only one redirect instead of multiple ones. I really do interested in simple sequential redirects, nothing difficult like parallel multi-threading. My code in view looks like this:

```
for code in codes:
            print(code)

            base_url = 'https://base_url/'
            code_part = 'code={}'.format(code)
            url = '{}?{}'.format(base_url, code_part)
            return redirect(url)
```

I thought about enveloping this into the parent-child function, which will process itself so many times as the structure of the list goes, but I think I will end up with the same result as normal for loop. Also, I saw redirects application, but I am not sure if it helps me with this exact task. And it doesn't matter how I implement it, but as soon as I call redirect, the program quits to the external web site and function stops.

**update**
I was asked to provide more of the code, so it helps to give the answer to my question. But that is the thing, that only relevant code is in my view function, which I included in the question, and I'm thinking at this time how to approach the question, so I don't have any other code at this time. Unfortunately :( Any push to the right direction would be very helpful. Thank you!

**update**
Unfortunately, redirects app for Django doesn't suit to do many queries to one site with different parameters. It suppose to handle 404 mistake, and creates moved permanently link in its table...

Comment: What is this method redirect, is it one you defined yourself?

Comment: I don't completely understand the question... I though about something like:  function() do redirect if I have more objects return this same function. It creates tree while I have more objects in a list. Sorry, in comments it is not possible to do function style writing. The problem is, it still won't work, because as soon as I call redirect it quits to external site.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem i see in your code was the indentation.
I just rewrote your code so it is a little simpler.
Maybe the problem is in the method called `redirect()` that you are returning in the end of your loop.

```
for code in codes:
    print(code)
    return redirect(f'https://base_url/?{code}')
```

And also when you return something then you actually quits the whole function. This means that whatever function your for loop is a part of, actually stops, and the for loop will never go any further than the first itteration.

So if you want the results from each code then you should write this instead:

```
results = []
for code in codes:
    print(code)
    results.append(redirect(f'https://base_url/?{code}'))
return results
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the thing... It quits, but I'm looking for multiple returns :(

Comment: Ok i updated the function so you return the list results

Comment: But again, as soon as I start to return each item in a list, and query external web site I quit to this external web site... But i think to append to a list is a good idea because I can create links with queries. But it would be nice to do multiple queries in one view function. But I don't really understand how to do it without falling into the trap of getting to external website.

Comment: I hope it was helpful. You need to share more of your code if you want more help, because it if impossible to understand what the problem is, when the only thing you show is this. for loop :)

Comment: I will post more code later, I have to be going home right now. But thank you for the help. If I find a solution I will post it here for others, because right now I cannot find any answer to it. The best tail I saw for right now, it's using redirection application for django. It said to be multithread and helps to django to deal with these kind of tasks. Thank you and have a great day!